# ​ Uncaught Error: Module not found: "./library" Parent module folder was: "/"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, npm, module, node-modules

In my project I keep getting an error when I try to load in a module. When I try to import it from the node_modules folder I get the error:

```
 ​ Uncaught Error: Module not found: "./MyLibrary". Parent module folder was: "/"
```

But, if I copy the `MyLibrary.js` file to the same directory then it imports fine.

Is there something I'm missing?

Here is the code:

Not working:

```
const MyLibrary = require("MyLibrary");
```

Working:

```
const MyLibrary = require("./MyLibrary").MyLibrary;
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "MyLibrary": "^1.4.8"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If I write out the entire path to the library it starts to work but then it errors on one of it's dependencies.

```
const Sval = require('/node_modules/MyLibrary/dist/MyLibrary');
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module not found: "MyLibraryDependen". Parent module folder was: "/node_modules/MyLibrary/dist".
```

**UPDATE 2:**
It looks like the environment I'm in doesn't do module resolution like nodejs does.

> ...you would need to use something like webpack to be able to require() stuff from node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the environment I am working in doesn't do module resolution.

I found webpack and that is supposed to fix this.

But what I did instead was copy the library.js to the project directory and all the referenced classes (or put them in a sub folder) and updated the library paths.